# Forzar una excepción en una llamada a std::rethrow_if_nested(e)

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando testear un método que lanza una excepción anidada mediante cobertura del siguiente código.

```
void foo(){
 try {
  std::rethrow_if_nested(e); //Aquí debe ocurrir la excepción
 }
 catch {
  cout << "WORKS" << endl;
 }
}
```

Me gustaría saber si puedo forzar la ejecución del catch de algún modo, o por el contrario al no contemplar el método rethrow_if_nested un error es imposible que se produzca una excepción en ese bloque desde una llamada externa a la función foo.

Comment: Necesitas una excepción que contenga otra excepción para que funcione. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/rethrow_if_nested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como comenta Mateo en referencia a [documentación rethrow_if_nested c++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/rethrow_if_nested), este problema puede resolverse mediante:

```
void foo(){
 try {
   std::throw_with_nested( std::runtime_error("Couldn't open " + s) ); //Ahora sí ocurre 
 }
 catch {
  cout << "WORKS" << endl;
 }
}
```

Para probar esto mediante `gtest` podemos realizar:

```
TEST(ExceptionT, NestedException){
  EXPECT_DEATH(foo(), "Nested_exception");
}
```